# Problem to wp_hash

Tags: user-meta

I have this code for an email:
 $hash = wp_hash_password ($user_info->user_pass);
 $address_invoice=$user_info->display_name.'
Email:'.$user_info->user_email.'
Username:'.$user_info->user_login.'
Password:'.$hash;

In the email:
I receive correctly name, email, username but not the password of user.

Why? What is it wrong?

Comment: Few questions - what action is this code hooked to? Are you intending to send the actual password itself and you're receiving a random-looking string? Or are you trying to send the hash and receiving nothing? Either way, it's worth noting that emailing either is something of a security hazard